# Como somar valores no keyup usando angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um campo que preciso que conforme for digitando valores, ele vai somando em uma variável.

Tentei algo como:

```
<input (keyup)="somaEstoque($event)"  #inputestoque type="text" name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" class="form-control" id="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">

  somaEstoque(valor){
    this.produto.estoque = this.produto.estoque + toFloat(valor.target.value);
  }
```

Meu alvo a ser somado é um formgroup que pode possuir "N" inputs de estoque:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="md-form form-lg input-modal">
       <input mask="000000000000" (keyup)="somaEstoque($event)"  #inputestoque type="text" name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" class="form-control" id="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">
       <label [class.active]="inputestoque.value != ''" for="estoque_variacao{{i}}">Estoque</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Acredito que a lógica é um pouco mais complexa, e tem também que tratar quando o usuário deleta o valor.

Alguém já fez isso no angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quem se interessar, consegui dessa maneira:

```
  soma(){
    let sum = 0;
    Object.keys(this.controls).map(key => {
      sum +=  +this.controls[key];
    });
    this.produto.estoque = sum;
  }

 <input mask="000000000000" [(ngModel)]="controls[i]" (keyup)="soma($event)" #inputestoque type="text" name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" class="form-control" id="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">
```